# Подмена координат в Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь отобразить карту, сделанную в конструкторе карт.

Вот сама карта - https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3A009993324c09277f5bd3c9665d62b88761fccb129da081b683f4f251f46f10cc&source=constructorLink

Копирую локально код из примера

https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

Введённый мной объект отображается, но не Санкт-Петербурге (хотя ставлю центрирование в  center: [29.902651, 60.02], как в примере), а где-то в Иране.

Такое ощущение, что меняются местами координаты longitude и latitude. Отчего может такое происходить и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ну так поменяйте координаты местами

Comment: Теряется весь смысл использования конструктора. Подразумевалось, что карта будет отображаться именно в том виде, что редактируется в нём. И, конечно, интересует, почему это вообще происходит. Песочница утверждает, что файлы можно использовать напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. По умолчанию Яндекс-карты принимают координаты в режиме ширина-долгота. Примеры из сандбокса работают в обратном режиме. Для того, чтобы они отображались нормально на сайте, нужно при инициализации скрипта Яндекса добавить параметр coordorder=longlat.